# How do I generate a valid SSL certificate for a nodejs, express, socket.io server using openssl?

Tags: express, websocket, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm currently trying to setup a websocket server to use for a AzureDevOps Server Extension. This means that i have to use wss and in turn need a SSL certificate.

I'm trying to use a self-selfsigned certificate created with openssl, but both Chrome and Firefox reject it with ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CER respectively.

I'm currently generating my certificate like this:
`& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe' req -new -nodes -x509 -days 365 -keyout $keyFile -out $certFile -config .\certificate-request -in cert.pem -copy_extensions copyall`

...the request config looks like this:

```
[req]
default_bits = 4096
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
OU = Self-Signed Certificate
CN = 127.0.0.1
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

(I have been playing around a bit, so there might be things I don't actually need in there)

...and my server is setup like this:

```
import * as logger from "./logger";
import * as fs from "fs";

import { createServer } from "https";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = require("express")();

const server = createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync("../config/server.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("../config/server.crt"),
    },
    app
);

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

server.listen(9000, () => {
    logger.logStandard("listening on *:9000");
});

//socket.io setup...
```